# Comma-separated values in ini config files

Tags: python, ini

How do i take input as a comma separated value in `ini` files when I'm parsing it with python in Linux.

Below you'll find the `MWE`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import configparser

def parse_config(file):
        global config_dictionary
        config_dictionary={}
        config=configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(file)
        for section in config.sections():
                config_dictionary[section] = {}
                for option in config.options(section):
                        config_dictionary[section][option] = config.get(section, option)
        return config_dictionary

def main():
        config_path = 'test.ini'
        config_dict=parse_config(config_path)
        mapping = config_dict['Options']['initialassignment']
        mapping = list(mapping)
        print mapping

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

and the `test.ini` file is

```
[Options]
initialAssignment=0,1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping = config_dict['Options']['initialassignment']
mapping = list(mapping)
mapping = [int(x) for x in mapping if x != ","]
print mapping
```

This definitely is not the cleanest way. but it works. Any suggestions will be helpful!. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes in your ini file:

[Options]

initialAssignment="0,1,2,3"

that will disable ',' as field separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `split()` method and list comprehension to split comma separated values and convert it to a list:

```
mapping = config_dict['Options']['initialassignment']
mapping = list(mapping)
mapping = [int(z) for z in (mapping.split(','))]
```

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongside code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value."